# Proof a property of a term including double summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the $i$th term as
$$t_i=(k n)! \sum _{j=1}^{k (n-1)+1} \frac{p_j }{(j-1)! (k n-j)!}\sum _{q=0}^{k n-j} (-1)^q \binom{n k-j}{q}(j+q)^{i-1}$$
where $n,k$ are finite positive integers as $2\leq n\leq k$ and $i=1,2,3,\cdots$. Probabilities $p_j$s come from an array length $k (n-1)+1$ where $\sum_j p_j=1$.

When I checked this term for different $n,k,i$ numerically using Mathematica, I found that $t_i=0$ for $i=1,\cdots, k-1$.

But I could not prove it mathematically. Can someone please guide me to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $t_i=0$ for some combinations of $n$ and $k$, and hence becomes independent of the values of $p_j$ already indicates that it is the sum over $q$ that makes this happen. To prove this we start with the general binomial expansion:
$$
(a + b)^m = \sum_{q=0}^m \binom{m}{q} b^{m-k} a^q
$$
for some integer $m \geq 1$ and apply the operation $a \frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ several times, say $l \geq 0$ times, on both the left and right hand side. This gives us 
$$
\left[a \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right]^l (a + b)^m = \sum_{q=0}^m \binom{m}{q} b^{m-k} \left[a \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right]^l a^q = \sum_{q=0}^m \binom{m}{q} b^{m-k} q^l a^q
$$
which is generally true for all $a,b$ and integers $l,m$. It is easy to prove/convince your self that for $l<m$ the left hand side is divisible by $(a+b)^{m-l}$, and therefore if we insert $a=-1$, $b=1
$, and restrict $0 \leq l < m$ that we get the general result
$$
\sum_{q=0}^m (-)^q \binom{m}{q} q^l = 0
$$
and from that it follows immediately that
$$
\sum_{q=0}^m (-)^q \binom{m}{q} (j+q)^l = 0
$$
for any value of $j$ and $0 \leq l < m$. Setting $m = k n - j$ and $l=i-1$ we find that the $j$th term of $t_i$ is zero whenever $0 \leq i-1 < k n - j$ and hence we get $$j < kn-i+1$$
The sum over $j$ however is restricted by
$$1 \leq j \leq kn - k + 1 < kn -i+1$$
for all $1 \leq i<k$, and therefore every term in the summation over $j$ is identical zero, which gives the results that $t_i=0$ for $1 \leq i < k$.

Note that neither the restriction $n \leq k$ nor the actual values of the $p_i$ are required for this to be true, but it might be imposed by the underlying problem of interest.

Comment: Thanks @Ronald, I did not quite understand the LHS of the third expression. Is it possible you to give bit more details on it? Or is it a common identity?

Comment: Ah, sorry a typo, meant to insert $a=-1$ and $b=1$, otherwise indeed it does not make sense.

Comment: Interesting proof, thank @Ronald.